# Adjusting dose rate, Image quality, X-ray Flurocopy

Tags: biophysics, medical-physics

When adjusting the dose rate, in this procedure from either film or detector the image quality would become poor due to less photons being transmitted via the x-ray tube.

How many ways with respect to Fluoroscope can one alter the dose rate, and how would it effect the image in each case?

So far all I can think of it altering the current, by doing this less photons are passing through the patient, which mean that less photos are being converted to electrons in the image intensifier, or scintillations in the respect to digital detectors, so this would result in a low resolution or less Sharpe image image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, decreasing the dose rate to the detector results in increased image noise, affecting low contrast detectability (harder to see differences between objects with similar density). High contrast resolution isn't necessarily affected.